# /usr/bin/python3: No module named colab_kernel_launcher

Tags: python, google-cloud-colab-enterprise

I need python==3.7 and am working on Google Colab.
The list of commands to downgrade the Python version are as follows:

```
!python --version 
!sudo apt-get install python3.7
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
```

It seems to work:

```
!python --version
```

output --

```
Python 3.7.17
```

However, when I restart the runtime according to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-downgrade-python-version-in-colab/

However, when I restart the runtime, it doesn't reconnect. These are logs from app.log

```
Feb 28, 2024, 3:17:22 PM    WARNING /usr/bin/python3: No module named colab_kernel_launcher
Feb 28, 2024, 3:17:22 PM    WARNING WARNING:root:kernel 30b3411f-a987-403e-9ac5-1fcc10285314 restarted
Feb 28, 2024, 3:17:22 PM    INFO    KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), keep random ports
Feb 28, 2024, 3:17:19 PM    WARNING /usr/bin/python3: No module named colab_kernel_launcher
Feb 28, 2024, 3:17:19 PM    WARNING WARNING:root:kernel 30b3411f-a987-403e-9ac5-1fcc10285314 restarted
Feb 28, 2024, 3:17:19 PM    INFO    KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5), keep random ports
Feb 28, 2024, 3:17:16 PM    WARNING /usr/bin/python3: No module named colab_kernel_launcher
Feb 28, 2024, 3:17:16 PM    WARNING WARNING:root:kernel 30b3411f-a987-403e-9ac5-1fcc10285314 restarted
Feb 28, 2024, 3:17:16 PM    INFO    KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5), keep random ports
Feb 28, 2024, 3:17:13 PM    WARNING /usr/bin/python3: No module named colab_kernel_launcher
```